# Показ банеров на сайте из txt файла

Tags: php, php7

Помогите пожалуйста? На сайте надо показывать баннеры рекламы и есть код php. Но проблема ругается на строчку последнюю         `print "<a href="$item[2]"><img src="$item[0]" alt="$item[1]"><br/>$item[1]</a>";`

```
    <?
  $ini="../tizer.txt"; 
$adv=file($ini);
$c=1;
$out = mt_rand(0, count($adv) - $c);
$sad=$out+$c;
for($i = $out; $iuu < $sad; $i++) {
$item = explode("::",$adv[$i]);
$item[2]=trim($item[2]);
print "<a href="$item[2]"><img src="$item[0]" alt="$item[1]"><br/>$item[1]</a>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print "<a href=".$item[2]."><img src=".$item[0]." alt=".$item[1]."><br/>".$item[1]."</a>";
```

ну и весь код бы я заменил на

```
$ini="../tizer.txt"; 
$adv=file($ini);
$item = explode("::", array_rand( array_flip($adv) ) );
echo <a href=".trim($item[2])."><img src=".$item[0]." alt=".$item[1]."><br/>".$item[1]."</a>";
```

Comment: Да кавычки забыли и потом почему то сама картинка не отображается ???